# How do I get to 100% in Gran Turismo 2?

Tags: gran-turismo-2

I have trophies showing for all of the main races, all of the maker races, and I've got the red-circle in all of the "arcade mode" races, but I'm still at only 96.86%.  What do I need to do for the last 3.14%?

Comment: Does buying cars affect the percentage complete? Maybe you need to buy every single car in the game?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it does.  Besides, there's hundreds of cars available, and you can only have 100 in your garage at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly you need to complete all of the manufacturer events. Check through them all - particularly Vauxhall/Opel (as this is technically two manufacturers that are interchanged based on your chosen language in the EU version, it just displays Opel elsewhere)

If you have all the Vauxhall events complete, try to get an "Opel" and do them again (which would require you to play in a different language to acquire).

Not certain if this is 100% accurate but I remember that the Vauxhall/Opel thing caused problems for people in the past, maybe this is the issue you have now.

Answer (score 1):

If you play the first version of the American version (v1.00), there is a bug that caps the total percentage achievable at 98.2% instead of 100%. Get an updated copy of the game to be able to attain 100% completion.

Comment: @Vemonus It's offering a solution to the problem the OP is facing: using an updated version of the game. I really don't see what you think is wrong here.

Comment: @Vemonus I'm not saying either of you are wrong - but the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Turismo_2) for this game says "Upon the game's release, players shortly found various errors and glitches. SCEA did not ignore the outcry, and offered a replacement if any problems occurred.[7](http://www.ign.com/articles/2000/01/21/sony-answers-gt2-questions) For example, the maximum attainable completion percentage was 98.2%."  This answer may actually uphold.

Comment: @TimmyJim yeah, I just found that as well. Removed my previous comments appropriately and edited the answer for clarity. Though since OP wasn't capped there, this still may not solve the issue.

Comment: @Vemonus possibly, the OP could have still missed something despite saying they finished everything they know of.  But given that this question is so old, and the user hasn't been seen since the same date as the question, we will likely never know.